# A way of abstracting a breadth-first list traversal

Tags: functional-programming, common-lisp

I wrote a simple/naive graph traversal in breadth-first, and then was playing with it to apply a simple tree, instead of a structured graph that easily bends itself to this function. I'm afraid I'm having difficulty coming up with a get-children lambda that'll yield the result I want, and it seems to be a nice brain-teaser to have a go at. Here it is:

The breadth-first function is:

```lisp
(defun run-breadth-first (node fn get-children)
  "Run fn breadth-first starting from node, traversing the whole tree."
  (let ((queue (list node)))
    (loop for i = (first queue)
          for inners = (if i (funcall get-children i) nil)
          until (null i)
          when inners do (setf queue (append queue inners))
          do 
          (funcall fn i)
          (pop queue))))
```

Btw, if anyone is wondering why I'm doing this, because I found it a nice abstraction to apply, and have a find call of one line to do a search as such:

```
(run-breadth-first sg-node #'find-sg-at-aux #'inner-nodes)
```

Now the difficulty I'm having is, I'd like to see this run with a regular list, instead of a custom graph structure with get-children functions returning a list of children. Here is an attempt with a simple 5-am test syntax:

```
(test run-breadth-first.test.list
      (let (output)
        (run-breadth-first '(1 2 (3 (4.1 4.2)) 5 (6 (6.1)) 7)
                           (lambda (node) (push (first node) output))
                           (lambda (node) (if (atom (first node))
                                              (list (rest node))
                                            (list (append (rest node) (first node)))))))
      (is (equal output (reverse '(1 2 5 7 3 6 4.1 4.2 6.1)))))
```

But when you run the statement inside, which is here for easy copying and separation:

```
(let (output)
        (run-breadth-first '(1 2 (3 (4.1 4.2)) 5 (6 (6.1)) 7)
                           (lambda (node) (push (first node) output))
                           (lambda (node) (if (atom (first node))
                                              (list (rest node))
                                            (list (append (rest node) (first node))))))
        output)
```

it returns:

```
(6.1 4.2 4.1 #1=(6.1) 6 #2=(4.1 4.2) 3 7 (6 #1#) 5 (3 #2#) 2 1)
```

The order of elements are correct, except the inner-lists. I'm yet to find a way to give me the result:

```
(6.1 4.2 4.1 6 3 7 5 2 1)
```

Could anyone see a solution?

Comment: Interesting, why don't I do the filtering in the fn lambda? It does give the required result that way, but is not a general solution, is it? We may want something that yields itself to further abstractions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, using just lambda functions was taking the valuable tool 'trace' away, and writing the function explicitly helped me shape it further.

Here is one function that'll give the correct result:

```
(defun get-list-children (node)
  (if (atom (first node))
      (if (atom (second node))
          (list (rest node))
        (list (append (rest (rest node)) (second node))))
    (list (append (rest node) (first node)))))
```

then call it:

```
(let (output)
        (run-breadth-first '(1 2 (3 (4.1 4.2)) 5 (6 (6.1)) 7)
                           (lambda (node) (push (first node) output))
                           #'get-list-children)
        output)
```